# Problem getting value in a form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe

Edit : I have found the solution.  ITEM_ID need to be 4 characters.  Is it okay to edit my post with the answer ? I'm new here.  Thanks!

---

I'm in my first step with Javascript so maybe the solution is quite obvious but I can't figure out.

I need to modify a stamp in Adobe.  When the user insert this stamp, a Javascript form appear.  There is already a group of radiobutton and it's working fine (in the code above, "rRec").

What I need to do is add another group of radiobutton (in the code above, "rNat").  I can't get the value of which radiobutton was check. "dialogConformiteFR.NatChoix" return nothing.  By doing some test, I realize that (results["rNat1"]), (results["rNat2"]) and (results["rNat3"]) never return true when it's checked on the form.

Hope I'm being enough clear, if not let me know.

This is not the complete code since there is a lot more to it, I just kept the radiobutton part.

```js
var dialogConformiteFR = 
{ 
    NatChoix: "", 
    Recommandation: "",

    DoDialog: function(){return app.execDialog(this);},
    initialize: function(dialog)
    {
        dialog.load({
            img1: "STCO", 
            lCie: "ST_CO"
        })
    },
    commit: function(dialog)
    {   
        //those return true if check
        if(results["rRe1"]) this.Recommandation = 1;
        else if(results["rRe2"]) this.Recommandation = 2;
        else if(results["rRe3"]) this.Recommandation = 3;
        else if(results["rRe4"]) this.Recommandation = 4;
        else if(results["rRe5"]) this.Recommandation = 5;
  
        //those return nothing when checked
        if(results["rNat1"]) this.NatChoix = 1;
        else if(results["rNat2"]) this.NatChoix = 2;
        else if(results["rNat3"]) this.NatChoix = 3;
    }

elements:
[
    type: "radio", 
    item_id: "rNat1", 
    group_id: "rNat", 
    name: "Dessin"

    type: "radio", 
    item_id: "rNat2", 
    group_id: "rNat", 
    name: "Plan"

    type: "radio", 
    item_id: "rNat3", 
    group_id: "rNat", 
    name: "Autres"

    type: "radio", 
    item_id: "rRe1", 
    group_id: "rRec", 
    name: "Fournir tel que soumis",

    type: "radio", 
    item_id: "rRe2", 
    group_id: "rRec", 
    name: "Fournir tel que corrigé",

    type: "radio", 
    item_id: "rRe3", 
    group_id: "rRec", 
    name: "Corriger et resoumettre",

    type: "radio", 
    item_id: "rRe4", 
    group_id: "rRec", 
    name: "Refusé",

    type: "radio",
    item_id: "rRe5", 
    group_id: "rRec", 
    name: "Autre (voir constatations)",

//no value in dialogConformiteFR.NatChoix;
this.getField("P2-Choix").value = dialogConformiteFR.NatChoix; 

//dialogConformiteFR.Recommandation has value in it
this.getField("P2-Rec").value = dialogConformiteFR.Recommandation;
```

Note : this would work fine : this.getField("P2-Choix").value = 2, the second radiobutton would be checked.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution !!

I can't believe I've wasted all those time because of that ...

So here it is, simple as that : ITEM_ID need to be 4 characters maximum

item_id: "rNat1" --> nop, not good, there is 5 characters !

Comment: Creating a question and answear by yourself is not the stackoverflow objective

Comment: Oh sorry, I have search for this problem for many hours and I thought I could let people know in case someone is looking for an answer one day.  So I'll guess I'll just delete my post instead of wanting to be helpful ! :-(